# Installing node packages globally offline

Tags: node.js, npm

**Environment:** In a closed/offline environment.
**Question:** I am manually copying over node_module's and one of them needs to be installed globally. What is the process to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the module is on your computer in a folder.

```
npm install /path/to/folder/containing/package/json/ -g
```